# pagination inside user profile

Tags: php, sql

I have a pagination inside an user profile.

When I'm inside the test profile the URL is profile.php?uid=1

But now I want to use a pagination to wiev the information from a SQL database. 
When I try the pagination on another page it works fine, but as you know the pagination change the URL depends on what side your on.

So my problem is that the pagination change my profile.php?uid=1 to profile.php?page=2

Do you have any tips on how to fix that error ?

This is my pagination code.

```
/*pagination */ 
    $per_page = 5;
    //$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM users");

    $pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('file_name') FROM users WHERE  `user_name` = '{$_SESSION['username']}' ") or die(mysql_error()); 
    $pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) /$per_page);

    $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
    $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

    <?php  
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT $start, $per_page")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 echo "<table border cellpadding=1>"; 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
    { ?><?php
        echo "<tr>"; 
//      echo "<td>".$info['user_id'] . "</td> "; 
        echo "<td>".$info['user_name'] . "</td> ";
    //  echo "<td>".$info['file_name'] . "</td> ";
        ?>
        <td> <a href="download.php?user_id=<?php echo $info['user_id'];?>"> <?php echo $info['file_name']; ?></a></td>
        <?php
        echo "<td>".date('d/m/Y') . "</td>" ;


    }
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>"; 


 if($pages >= 1 && $page <=$pages){

 for ($x = 1; $x<=$pages; $x++){ 

 echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href="?page='.$x.'">' .$x. '</a> </strong>' : '<a href="?page=' .$x. '">' .$x. ' </a> ';

 }

 }

 ?>
```

/*pagination */

And the profile

function fetch_user_info($uid){
    $uid = (int)$uid;

```
    $sql = "SELECT
    `user_name` AS `username`,
    `user_email` AS `email`
FROM `users`
WHERE `user_id` = {$uid} ";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

}

```
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") or die(mysql_error()); 

$files = mysql_query("SELECT `file_name` FROM users WHERE  `user_name` = '{$_SESSION['username']}' ") or die(mysql_error()); 
$user_info = fetch_user_info($_GET['uid']);
```

I really dont have a clue on how to fix this =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not passing the user id in your pager links, try changing this line...

```
echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href="?page='.$x.'">' .$x. '</a> </strong>' : '<a href="?page=' .$x. '">' .$x. ' </a> ';
```

to

```
echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href="?uid='.$_GET['uid'].'&page='.$x.'">' .$x. '</a> </strong>' : '<a href="?uid='.$_GET['uid'].'&page=' .$x. '">' .$x. ' </a> ';
```

Comment: Hmm, well the pagination works, but I still get loged out and the url shows
profile.php?user_id=&page=2  =(

Comment: I still get the index error =/
and the url 
?user_id=1&page=2

Comment: What index error? Your original question indicates you weren't passing the uid in your request, my answer fixes that, but this is the first I'm hearing of an index error :-/

Comment: When the URL changes to profile.php?user_id=1&page=2 
its loging me out since I dont have a user with that profile name..

And the error is

undefined index: uid on line 27 that line is 
$user_info = fetch_user_info($_GET['uid']);  

And the same error on line 168

Thats where I use your answer

Comment: ah, ok, I see, it's a misunderstanding over variable names, one more edit should fix it :)

Comment: Remember to sanitize the $_GET value before going live.

Comment: Its working now!! omg :)

Thank you so much
If you are in Stockholm I buy you a beer :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `uid` on the session?

try

```
echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href="?page='.$x.'">' .$x. '</a> </strong>' : '<a href="?user_id=' . $_SESSION['uid'] . '&page=' .$x. '">' .$x. ' </a> ';
```

But, actually you do not really need it if you add session for your `uid`. You can change `fetch_user_info`

```
function fetch_user_info(){ 

    $sql = "SELECT
    `user_name` AS `username`,
    `user_email` AS `email`
FROM `users`
WHERE `user_id` = " . $_SESSION['uid'];

$result = mysql_query($sql);

return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

}
```

Comment: I tried the function above, but i still got the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

**Typo:**

```
    $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page'])) ? 1 : $_REQUEST['page'];
```

***Changed To***

```
    $page = (!isset($_REQUEST['page'])) ? 1 : $_REQUEST['page'];
```

Its a very simple solution. You basically "read" the URL/query string in the pagination code and automatically "append that to your URL. I wrote some simple plug and play code for you - that will easily do the trick (All you need is just 1 extra line of code and one include file - 'inc_pagination.php', - to ANY page that needs pagination. no modification of existing code):

```
/*pagination */  
$per_page = 5; 
include 'inc_pagination.php'; /* FIRST LINE ADDED TO YOUR CODE*/

$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('file_name') FROM users WHERE  `user_name` = '{$_SESSION['username']}' ") or die(mysql_error());  
$pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) /$per_page); 

/* REMOVING THESE TWO LINES */
/*  $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1; 
    $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page; */

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT $start, $per_page") or die(mysql_error());         
echo "<table border cellpadding=1>";                                    
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))                                    
{ ?><?php                                   
    echo "<tr>";                                    
    echo "<td>".$info['user_name'] . "</td> ";                                   
    ?>                                   
    <td> <a href="download.php?user_id=<?php echo $info['user_id'];?>"> <?php echo $info['file_name']; ?></a></td>                                   
    <?php                                   
    echo "<td>".date('d/m/Y') . "</td>" ;                                   

}                                   
    echo "</tr>";                                   
    echo "</table>";    

/* 2nd LINE ADDED (Replaces Existing Page Code) - Add this wherever you need page numbers displayed */
echo paginate_me(ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0)/$per_page), $per_page);
```

Please note that you need to obviously remove your existing pagination code block:

```
if($pages >= 1 && $page <=$pages){                      

   for ($x = 1; $x<=$pages; $x++){                       
      echo ($x == $page) ? '<strong><a href="?page='.$x.'">' .$x. '</a> </strong>' : '<a href="?page=' .$x. '">' .$x. ' </a> ';                      
   }                      

}
```

And finally here is the code for include file **'inc_pagination.php'**. Please note that this one has all the bells and whistles - including javascript for hover/mouseover and other visual effects - I can also include a really simple text only version if you like!

```
<?
//The number of page numbers you want displayed accross page in pagination bar
$nav_links_per_row = 35;
$page = (!isset($_REQUEST['page'])) ? 1 : $_REQUEST['page'];
$start = ($page == 1) ? 0 : ($page - 1) * $per_page ;
$per_page = (!$per_page) ? 5 : $per_page;

function paginate_me($no_of_pages, $per_page, $nav_links_per_row = 35) {

    $page = 1;
    $page = $_REQUEST['page'];
    $x_mid_start = 1;
    $x_mid_end = $no_of_pages;

     /* START: Here is the main code that detects all your existing QUERY STRING and AUTOMATICALLY includes them in the Page Links */
    $x_url = urldecode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    parse_str($x_url, $output);
    $qs = explode('?',urldecode($x_url));
     /* END: QUERY STRING DETECT CODE */ 

    $p_me .= "<br><table align = 'Center' width = '90%' cellpadding = '0' border = '0'><tr>";
    if ($no_of_pages > 35)
    {
        // Go Back 5
        if ( $page > 5 ){
            $bg_color = "White";
            $ObjTopBar = '"jTopBar_start"';
            $q_str = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            $jump = (int)$page - 5;
            $title = "User Files: Jump Back 5 Pages";
            $this_page = str_replace("page=$page","page=$jump","?".$q_str);
            $p_me .=  "<td><a title='$title' href='".$this_page."'> <div id=".$ObjTopBar." onMouseOver='javascript: onMouseOverOut(".$ObjTopBar.")' onMouseOut='javascript: onMouseOverOut(".$ObjTopBar.")' style='border: 1px solid silver; border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; width: 20px; height: 15px; text-align: center; background: ".$bg_color."; color: #333333; vertical-align:middle;padding-top: 2px; overflow:auto'>-</div></a></td>";
        }

        //1 to 10
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++) 
        {
            if ($i == $page) $bg_color = "orange";
                else $bg_color = "#333333";
            if (!$page) $bg_color = "orange";

            $ObjTopBar = '"jTopBar'.$i.'"';
            $q_str = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            $this_page = str_replace("page=$page","page=$i","?".$q_str);
            $title = "User Files: Jump to Page $i";

            $p_me .=  "<td><a title='$title' href='".$this_page."'> <div id=".$ObjTopBar." onMouseOver='javascript: onMouseOverOut(".$ObjTopBar.")' onMouseOut='javascript: onMouseOverOut(".$ObjTopBar.")' style='border: 1px solid silver; border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; width: 20px; height: 15px; text-align: center; background: ".$bg_color."; color: white; vertical-align:middle;padding-top: 2px; overflow:auto'>".$i."</div> </a></td>";
        }

        //Set Starting Page Numbers for Mid Block If Page Count is > 35
        $p_me .=  "<td> <font color=white>... </td>";
        $x_mid_start = floor($no_of_pages / 2) - 5 ;
        $x_mid_end = floor($no_of_pages / 2) + 5 ;

        //if selected page is between half - 5  to half + 5 SHOW start: selected page, end: selected page + 9
        if (($page > 8) && ($page < $no_of_pages - 8)) {
            $x_mid_start = $page - 5;
            $x_mid_end = $page + 5;
        }
    }

    //Empty Blocks...First Few Spaces...if Page Count < 35
    if ($no_of_pages < 35) {    
        for ($k = 1; $k <= floor((35 - $no_of_pages) / 2); $k++)    
            {
                $ObjTopBarLinks = '"divBEnd_'.$k.'"'; 
                $ObjTopBarEmpty = '"divBStart'.$k.'"';
                $p_me .=  "<td><div id=".$ObjTopBarEmpty." onMouseOver='javascript: onMouseOverOutE(".$ObjTopBarLinks.")' onMouseOut='javascript: onMouseOverOutE(".$ObjTopBarLinks.")' style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; border: 1px solid silver;  border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; width: 20px; height: 15px; text-align: center; background: grey; color: white; vertical-align:middle;padding-top: 2px; overflow:auto'> </div></td>";
            }
    }

    // Print Page Numbers in the Center
    for ($i = $x_mid_start; $i <= $x_mid_end; $i++) 
        {
            if ($i == $page) $bg_color = "orange";
                else $bg_color = "#333333";
            if (!$page) $bg_color = "orange";

            $ObjTopBar = '"jTopBar'.$i.'"';
            $q_str = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            $this_page = str_replace("page=$page","page=$i","?".$q_str);
            $title = "User Files: Jump to Page $i";

            $p_me .=  "<td><a title='$title' href='".$this_page."'> <div id=".$ObjTopBar." onMouseOver='javascript: onMouseOverOut(".$ObjTopBar.")' onMouseOut='javascript: onMouseOverOut(".$ObjTopBar.")' style='border: 1px solid silver; border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; width: 20px; height: 15px; text-align: center; background: ".$bg_color."; color: white; vertical-align:middle;padding-top: 2px; overflow:auto'>".$i."</div> </a></td>";
        }

    //Empty Blocks...Last Few Spaces...If Page Count < 35
    if ($no_of_pages < 35) {    
        for ($k = 1; $k <= ceil(($nav_links_per_row - $x_mid_end)/2); $k++) 
            {
                $ObjTopBarLinks = '"divBStart'.$k.'"';
                $ObjTopBarEmpty = '"divBEnd_'.$k.'"';
                $p_me .=  "<td><div id=".$ObjTopBarEmpty." onMouseOver='javascript: onMouseOverOutE(".$ObjTopBarLinks.")' onMouseOut='javascript: onMouseOverOutE(".$ObjTopBarLinks.")' style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; border: 1px solid silver;  border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; width: 20px; height: 15px; text-align: center; background: grey; color: white; vertical-align:middle;padding-top: 2px; overflow:auto'> </div></td>";
            }
    }
    else
    {   
        //Page Count is > 35
        $p_me .=  "<td> <font color=white>... </td>";
        //no_of_pages-10 to end
        for ($i = $no_of_pages - 8; $i <= $no_of_pages; $i++) 
        {

            if ($i == $page) $bg_color = "orange";
                else $bg_color = "#333333";
            if (!$page) $bg_color = "orange";

            $ObjTopBar = '"jTopBar'.$i.'"';
            $q_str = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            $this_page = str_replace("page=$page","page=$i","?".$q_str);
            $title = "User Files: Jump to Page $i";
            $p_me .=  "<td><a title='$title' href='".$this_page."'> <div id=".$ObjTopBar." onMouseOver='javascript: onMouseOverOut(".$ObjTopBar.")' onMouseOut='javascript: onMouseOverOut(".$ObjTopBar.")' style='border: 1px solid silver; border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; width: 20px; height: 15px; text-align: center; background: ".$bg_color."; color: white; vertical-align:middle;padding-top: 2px; overflow:auto'>".$i."</div> </a></td>";
        }

        // Go Forward 5
        if ( $page < $no_of_pages - 5 ){
            $bg_color = "White";
            $ObjTopBar = '"jTopBar_end"';
            $q_str = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            $jump = (int)$page + 5;
            $title = "User Files: Jump Forward 5 Pages";
            $this_page = str_replace("page=$page","page=$jump","?".$q_str);
            $p_me .=  "<td><a title='$title' href='".$this_page."'> <div id=".$ObjTopBar." onMouseOver='javascript: onMouseOverOut(".$ObjTopBar.")' onMouseOut='javascript: onMouseOverOut(".$ObjTopBar.")' style='border: 1px solid silver; border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; width: 20px; height: 15px; text-align: center; background: ".$bg_color."; color: #333333; vertical-align:middle;padding-top: 2px; overflow:auto'>+</div></a></td>";           }
    }
            $p_me .=  "</tr></table><br>";
    return $p_me;
}   
?>


<script type="text/javascript">

function onMouseOverOut(Obj) {
    setTimeout(function() { onMouseOverOut1(Obj) }, 300);
}

function onMouseOverOut1(x) {

    var ODiv = document.getElementById(x);
    var currBg = ODiv.style.background;

    if (currBg == "orange") return false;
    if (x == "jTopBar_start") return false;
    if (x == "jTopBar_end") return false;

    if (ODiv.style.background.indexOf("red") < 0)
        ODiv.style.background = "red";
    else
    if (ODiv.style.background.indexOf("#333333") < 0)
            ODiv.style.background = "#333333";
}

function onMouseOverOutE(Obj) {
    setTimeout(function() { onMouseOverOutE1(Obj) }, 300);
}       

function onMouseOverOutE1(Obj) {
    var ODiv = document.getElementById(Obj);
    if (ODiv.style.border.indexOf("grey") < 0)
            ODiv.style.border = "1px solid grey";
    else
    if (ODiv.style.border.indexOf("silver") < 0)
            ODiv.style.border = "1px solid silver";

    if (ODiv.style.background.indexOf("white") < 0)
            ODiv.style.background = "white";
    else
    if (ODiv.style.background.indexOf("grey") < 0)
            ODiv.style.background = "grey";
}   
</script>
```